# Accessing a WSDL web service that requires a Header from a .Net solution client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

This is going to be a bit long so please bear with me.

I have been beating my head against this issue for quite some time.  I am not very experienced in web services from a client and am having real issues setting this up.  What I have is a web service from a third part hosted on a site.  The service is a WSDL service written in JAVA.  I am trying to connect to it from y .NET solution and consume the web services provided.  One of the requirements from the vendor is to "set the Headers parameter to 'XXXX' and the value to 'YYYY'"

I am having some serious issues doing this.  My first attempt was to simply add the web service as a web reference in Visual Studio (2012).  There were no methods exposed by the service to set the header so I simply called a function to see what happened.  I received an exception "No SOAP Headers specified".

Next I attempted to create a manual proxy using SVCUTIL.exe.  I think there may be something wrong with the web services because I receive errors "**Cannot import wsdl:binding**": **"Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled."**

However, the class and config files are still created.  Anyways, I imported the class into my web app and updated my web.config with the necessary settings from the proxy config.  I declare an instance of the needed class and this is where things go south for this attempt.  When declaring an instance of the class I receive the error "**could not find default end point element that references contract "ContractName" in the ServiceModel client configuration. This might be because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element**".  I am wondering if perhaps there is a problem with the services or they simply weren't designed for .NET.  The other obvious option is I am doing something wrong.  I would be happy to post the config file and such if you would like to see it (I just felt I had loaded this post enough as it is).

What I am really looking for is instructions (a tutorial would be awesome) on how to add a web service as a reference within Visual Studio c# application but being able to set the headers from within the code.

I am sorry for the length of this post.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try creating your proxy with `wsdl.exe` and override the `GetWebRequest` method. you can add custom values to `request.Header`